# Differentiating between 'moved text' vs 'deleted text' within a git commit?

Tags: git

I have a repository containing text written in org-mode syntax. Each file contains nested paragraphs. There are a few hundred files. During the writing process, parts of various documents have been able to move freely between very differently named files.

When stepping through small commits in the repo's history, I can manually see deleted blocks of text being added to other files. I can also see what text I have deleted and not added elsewhere. However, I'm am struggling to do this for larger commits involving larger numbers of files.

Is there is a way that git (or a related tool/pipe?) can help me determine what text was deleted in a commit vs what text was moved between two files?